# Winsock TCP Retransmission/Reset Protocol Details

Tags: windows, sockets, networking, tcp, winsock

First a little background:

I currently have a client that talks to a server over TCP.  Both client and server are running Windows and using WinSocks.  I send a variety of messages to the server and send at least one message every second.  Every 10 minutes, almost exactly, I'm seeing an issue where my server seems to stop replying to my client.  I then see 5 retransmissions from the client, using timeout doubling each time, then finally a RST pack is received on the client from the server.  This resets my client socket, a new port number is assigned, and communication then continues as normal for another 10 minutes.

Now a little Data:

I'm using wireshark to analyze this problem.  All data was captured on the client (192.168.110.1) side of the connection as the server is not easily accessible. Below is the relevant data (Sorry for the terrible formatting.  It's the only way I could figure out to get the data here):

```
RefNum|Source|Destination|Length|Packet Info

1 | 192.168.110.1 | 192.168.110.22 | 61 | 62314 > 7074 [PSH, ACK] Seq=693 Ack=8483 Win=63303 Len=7

2 | 192.168.110.1 | 192.168.110.22 | 75 | [TCP Retransmission] 62314 > 7074 [PSH, ACK] Seq=693 Ack=8483 Win=63303 Len=21

3 | 192.168.110.1 | 192.168.110.22 | 75 | [TCP Retransmission] 62314 > 7074 [PSH, ACK] Seq=693 Ack=8483 Win=63303 Len=21

4 | 192.168.110.1 | 192.168.110.22 | 89 | [TCP Retransmission] 62314 > 7074 [PSH, ACK] Seq=693 Ack=8483 Win=63303 Len=35

5 | 192.168.110.1 | 192.168.110.22 | 113 | [TCP Retransmission] 62314 > 7074 [PSH, ACK] Seq=693 Ack=8483 Win=63303 Len=59

6 | 192.168.110.1 | 192.168.110.22 | 135 | [TCP Retransmission] 62314 > 7074 [PSH, ACK] Seq=693 Ack=8483 Win=63303 Len=81

7 | 192.168.110.22 | 192.168.110.1 | 64 | 7074 > 62314 [RST] Seq=8483 Win=0 Len=0 [ETHERNET FRAME CHECK SEQUENCE INCORRECT]

8 | 192.168.110.1 | 192.168.110.22 | 66 | 62348 > 7074 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1

9 | 192.168.110.22 | 192.168.110.1 | 64 | 7074 > 62348 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=5840 Len=0 MSS=1460 [ETHERNET FRAME CHECK SEQUENCE INCORRECT]

10 | 192.168.110.1 | 192.168.110.22 | 54 | 62348 > 7074 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0

11 | 192.168.110.1 | 192.168.110.22 | 56 | 62348 > 7074 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=2

12 | 192.168.110.22 | 192.168.110.1 | 72 | 7074 > 62348 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=3 Win=5838 Len=18
```

1 - 6 - original and retransmitted packets
7 - Reset received from server
8 - 10 - new handshake between client and server with new client port number
11 - 12 - first new message and response with new client port number

Finally, a few questions:

As it's most likely apparent by now, I'm not a TCP guru (or even close).  I thought the Google was strong with me but I can't seem to track down the answers to the following questions:

1. I've noticed that the TCP RST packet originates from the server I'm talking to which is odd since this server is not replying to any of my other packets.  Is this actually the case or is there some TCP trickery going on here to make my client port "think" this packet is coming from the server when it is actually originating on the client side in an attempt to reset itself.
2. Is it possible for a socket to get in a state where it can send but not receive? This could explain the behavior I'm seeing but still doesn't explain how I'm able to receive the RST packet unless my assumption in 1 is correct.
3. I've noticed that the retransmission packets are growing in size...is this normal for TCP?  It appears that additional packets my client is attempting to send to the server are getting lumped into the retransmitted TCP packet.  Everything else appears to be functioning correctly (timeout doubling, etc.).

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Answers to your questions:

1. It's extremely doubtful the client sent the RST to itself and spoofed the server. If it did, you probably wouldn't see it on the wire anyway. Look at the src and dst MAC addresses, are they the same as the other traffic from the server?
2. Yes, if the receive buffer is full, it can not receive anything further, but it can send window updates, or presumably even data in the other direction.
3. Yes, this is normal. It's call [repacketization](http://flylib.com/books/en/3.223.1.226/1/). If the application has more data to send, TCP will add it to the retransmits.

Two things make me wonder if the RST is not from the server, but from an intermediate device or host firewall:

1. If communication has been happening for 10 minutes then the server has received data and has been ACKing it. In my experience, the RST will include an ACK number in this situation, yet that RST does not.
2. It occurs consistently at 10min. Sounds like a firewall or proxy timeout.

If it were a server application issue (the process is having a problem and stops reading data from the socket), TCP on the server would still acknowledge receiving the data, but its receive window would fill up. In this case since there are no ACKs, it seems the client's packets are being dropped or blocked somewhere in between.